# Passing argument to a rspec test example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I have some tests that are using a big, test database. I'm also using Database Cleaner to clean the database after each tests. And here comes the problem.
In my spec helper I have this

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
  MongoLib.new(database: "#{Rails.env}_sensor_data").drop_tables!
  DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
    example.run
  end
end
```

But, here's the problem. The mentioned group of tests (a big group), generates and drops this big database over and over again (once for each test). That takes a long time, and those tests does not change the database at all, so I don't really want to clean and create the database every time.

So, is there a way to do something like this:

```
it 'something', argument do
  #testing
end
```

So in the spec helper I can do something like this:

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
MongoLib.new(database: "#{Rails.env}_sensor_data").drop_tables!
  if example.argument?
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

Or maybe there is other solution for that problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Each `example` object in your around hook has the `metadata` method that returns a hash. So you can tag the tests you want to run the cleaner on, and look for that tag in your hook. Something like this:

```
it "does something", :db_clean do
  # ...
end

config.around(:each) do |example|
  if example.metadata[:db_clean]
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

You can learn more about these filters [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/filters#filter-%60around(:example)%60-hooks-using-arbitrary-metadata).

Comment: Exactly what I need, and exactly what I was looking for.